# Displaying blog style tags side by side in multiple rows (Android)

Tags: android, user-interface, tags

Please see the image below:
[image: Multiple Tags appearing side by side]

I want to display a set of tags side by side in an Android app.
Conditions are:

- Each tag appear next to the previous tag.
- If the horizontal space runs out, the next tag appears in a new line.
- If there are multiple words in a tag and there's only a space for some of the words of a tag, move the whole tag in a new line. However, if the tag was already in a new line, let the tag break in two lines.

I'm not sure what this technique is called. Any help on the issue, whether by code or link to a library, will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple libraries for tags, fo instance:

[**AndroidTagGroup**](https://github.com/2dxgujun/AndroidTagGroup)

Add to your xml:

```
<me.gujun.android.taggroup.TagGroup
    android:id="@+id/tag_group"
    style="@style/TagGroup" />
```

And add code:

```
TagGroup mTagGroup = (TagGroup) findViewById(R.id.tag_group);
mTagGroup.setTags(new String[]{"Tag1", "Tag2", "Tag3"});
```

Anoter solution is:

[**AutoLabelUI**](https://github.com/DavidPizarro/AutoLabelUI)

Add to xml:

```
<com.dpizarro.autolabel.library.AutoLabelUI
        android:id="@+id/label_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And add to code:

```
AutoLabelUI mAutoLabel = (AutoLabelUI) view.findViewById(R.id.label_view);

AutoLabelUISettings autoLabelUISettings = new AutoLabelUISettings.Builder()
                                                                 .withMaxLabels(5)
                                                                 .withIconCross(R.drawable.cross)
                                                                 .withBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright)
                                                                 .withLabelsClickables(false)
                                                                 .withShowCross(true)
                                                                 .withTextColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark)
                                                                 .withTextSize(R.dimen.label_title_size)
                                                                 .build();

mAutoLabel.setSettings(autoLabelUISettings);
```

Also, you may use [**HashtagView**](https://github.com/greenfrvr/hashtag-view)

Comment: Is there a way I can add padding and tag spacing in AutoLabelUI. OR I can remove rounded edges from AndroidTagGroup?

Answer (score 0):

@Umair 
you could also do the same thing from Xml as : `<com.dpizarro.autolabel.library.AutoLabelUI
                    android:id="@+id/label_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    autolabel:icon_cross="@drawable/cross"
                    autolabel:label_background_res="@color/light_greylabel"
                    autolabel:label_clickable="true"
                    autolabel:label_padding="5dp"
                    autolabel:max_labels="10"
                    autolabel:show_cross="true"
                    autolabel:text_color="@color/app_grey"
                    autolabel:text_size="@dimen/label_title_size" />`

you could get the library from [Here](https://github.com/DavidPizarro/AutoLabelUI)